# Numpy multidimensional array assigment unknown logic error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm confused as to why this bubble sort I'm implementing on a numpy array is setting *all* items to one of the items (I have no idea which one as array is too big)

the data type is of

```
...

[[1128 1026 1192 1023]]

[[ 771  195  858  196]]

[[ 953 1799  955 1738]]]
```

when I have an array of int, this same algorithm sorts it perfectly,

```
 g = [i for i in range(10)]

for i in range(0,len(g)):
    for j in range(0,len(g)):
        if(g[i]>g[j]):
            cnt = g[i]
            g[i] = g[j]
            g[j] = cnt
```

I presume my issue is that I do not understand multidimensional numpy array element assigment, please explain why this breaks:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),

                min_line_length, max_line_gap)
```

## sort by an 2nd element of each item

```
for i in range(0,len(lines)):

    for j in range(0,len(lines)):

        if(lines[i][0][1]<lines[j][0][1]):

            cnt = lines[i][0]

            lines[i][0] = lines[j][0]

            lines[j][0] = cnt[/CODE]
```

## now the array is

```
[[[ 738 1831  867 1831]]

...

[[ 738 1831  867 1831]]

[[ 738 1831  867 1831]]

[[ 738 1831  867 1831]]]
```

why? Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you get the same behaviour if you put `cnt = lines[i][0].copy()` and `lines[i][0] = lines[j][0].copy()`

Comment: perfection! thank you, if you post this as an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want your code to assign the value of a variable to a new object, your code is interpreted differently:

Quote from the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
>   mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
>   can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides
>   generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

I give an example with lists:

`a` is initialised as a list with one element that has value 9:

```
In [1]: a = [9]
```

Now

```
In [2]: b = a
```

while it may look like you just created an object with the same value as `a`, what this line of code does in actuality, is to create a reference to the `same` object.

So, assigning a new value to the first element of `a` will change the underlying object:

```
In [3]: a[0] = 1
```

And if the new name you gave this object is called, it will still reference to that object:

```
In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1]
```

To avoid unwanted behaviour, you should use `copy`:

```
In [1]: import copy

In [2]: a = [9]

In [3]: b = copy.copy(a)

In [4]: a[0] = 1

In [5]: b
Out[5]: [9]
```

`np.arrays` have a .copy() method, that you can call like so, without importing copy:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = a.copy()
```